# Hole in fork crown welding seam

Tags: fork, headset, noise, clicking

Some time ago I noticed a clicking noise somewhere in headset area. Noise appears under pressure, also it clicks when I tightening the headset. First thought was that problem is with headset bearings, because steering was like "indexed" in center.

So first what I did - replaced bearings and greased everything. Indexed steering had gone. But clicking noise remained. Yesterday I removed mudguard to check fork for the cracks and found this small hole where fork meets steerer tube. Can it be source for clicking noise? Is it dangerous to ride with it?

[image: Here is the picture of subject bike and hole]

Comment: Is the fork aluminum?  Or steel?  FWIW, that just looks like a bad weld.

Comment: @andrewhenle aluminium. i think it's 6061 alloy, at least manufacturer says so :)

Comment: I used to have very similar looking fork except with V-brake bosses. It also did the clicking noise. I replaced it with steel one when the clicking turned into crunching.

Comment: I don't see any cracks.  If there are no cracks then I doubt that this is a problem.

Comment: I don't think one should make safety judgements about a bicycle based on just a photograph, except in cases where the bicycle is obviously unsafe. I think you should take this into a bike shop to get the opinion of somebody who can actually examine the bike.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a poor weld. Notice there are other deliberately drilled holes in that area so an extra one is not a problem.

Clicking in the headset area is much more likely to be flex between the steerer and stem, stem and bars, or possibly the headset races pressed into the frame. If the click happens as you go over a bump or change force on the bars through pedal strokes that would point to those interfaces as a culprit.

Comment: It's fairly simple to check if it is the headset or fork: just remove the fork, grab it by steerer tube and push it against the ground in different angles. The similar looking fork I had made clicking sounds fine without headset or frame.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Thanks! Look like problem is with headset races. because when i remove fork and push it against ground it's not clicking. and i double checked stem and bars. i can hear that sound even if i remove stem and bars and just press down the frame near headset with my hands. I will try to press new races and then comment is it worked or not